# C#: What is the difference between MovedPermanently and Moved in HttpStatusCode

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, asp.net-web-api

Today when I tried to redirect action in web api I notice that there is two value about 301 redirect:

Value 1:

```
var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently);
response.Headers.Location = new Uri("http://www.example.com");
return response;
```

---

Value 2:

```
var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Moved);
response.Headers.Location = new Uri("http://www.example.com");
return response;
```

---

And now my question is which one is better and what is the different between two values of `HttpStatusCode`?

Comment: @IanMercer No it is different, Both of MovedPermanently and Moved are 301

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode(v=vs.110).aspx) document:

**Moved:**
Equivalent to HTTP status 301.

Moved indicates that the requested information has been moved to the URI specified in the Location header. The default action when this status is received is to follow the Location header associated with the response.

When the original request method was POST, the redirected request will use the GET method.

**MovedPermanently:**
Equivalent to HTTP status 301.

MovedPermanently indicates that the requested information has been moved to the URI specified in the Location header.

The default action when this status is received is to follow the Location header associated with the response.

Comment: Is it true?
Both are same expect in HTTP METHOD, Moved return GET anyway but MovedPermanently May return GET/POST depend of primary request.

Comment: Yes. you can find same from `MSDN` document.

Comment: Not anymore: "MovedPermanently is a synonym for Moved." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpstatuscode?view=netframework-4.8